# How to fix error 504: Gateway Timeout in express.js (v 4.0.0)?

Tags: node.js, express, connection-timeout

I am developing a server with express.js, which makes requests to github api to get the users's repositories within webhooks. The problem is that this request returns:

```
problem with request: timed out
[error] { [Error: 504: Gateway Timeout]
[error]   defaultMessage: 'Gateway Timeout',
[error]   message: '504: Gateway Timeout',
[error]   code: '504' }
```

My code:

- Service:

  exports.getWebHooks = function getWebHooks (githubtoken, arrRepos){

  ```
  var promise = new Hope.Promise();

  var arrReposDef = [];

  var github = new GitHubApi({
      version: "3.0.0",
      debug: true,
      protocol: "https",
      host: "api.github.com", // should be api.github.com for GitHub
      timeout: 5000,
      headers: {
          "user-agent": "Meanstack" // GitHub is happy with a unique user agent
      }
  });


  github.authenticate({
      type: "oauth",
      token: githubtoken.token
  });


  async.each(arrRepos,

      function(item, callback){
          // It runs well

          github.repos.getHooks({

              user: githubtoken.username,
              repo: item.name,

              headers: {
                  "X-GitHub-OTP": "two-factor-code"
              }

          }, function(err, res) { 
              if (err) { // it runs wrong 2 times, this the error that I defined up.
                  console.log(err);
                  githuberror = true;

              }

               else{ // it runs well 2 times



                  if(!res.length){

                      arrReposDef.push(item);


                  }

                  else{
                      var enc = false;

                      for(var i = 0; i< res.length; i++){
                          if(res[i].config !== undefined && res[i].config !== null){
                              if(res[i].config.url !== undefined && res[i].config.url !== null){



                                  if(res[i].config.url !== config.githubcallback){

                                       enc = true;


                                  }
                              }

                          }
                      }
                      if(enc) {


                          arrReposDef.push(item);


                      }


                  }



              }
              callback(); //required
          });
      },

      // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
      function(err){

          if(err){
              console.log('Error:' + err);
              return promise.done(err,null);
          }

          // All tasks are done now
          else{

              return promise.done(null,arrReposDef);


          }
      }
  );

  return promise;
  ```

  };

I know the application flow thanks to cmd result:

```
REQUEST:  { host: 'api.github.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/repos/1izpena/angularProject/hooks?access_token=secret',
  method: 'get',
  headers: 
   { host: 'api.github.com',
     'content-length': '0',
     'x-github-otp': 'two-factor-code',
     'user-agent': 'Meanstack',
     accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json' } }
entro en webhooks, dentro del callback
REQUEST:  { host: 'api.github.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/repos/1izpena/ionicProject/hooks?access_token=secret',
  method: 'get',
  headers: 
   { host: 'api.github.com',
     'content-length': '0',
     'x-github-otp': 'two-factor-code',
     'user-agent': 'Meanstack',
     accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json' } }
entro en webhooks, dentro del callback
REQUEST:  { host: 'api.github.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/repos/1izpena/ionicProjectDef/hooks?access_token=secret',
  method: 'get',
  headers: 
   { host: 'api.github.com',
     'content-length': '0',
     'x-github-otp': 'two-factor-code',
     'user-agent': 'Meanstack',
     accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json' } }
entro en webhooks, dentro del callback
REQUEST:  { host: 'api.github.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/repos/1izpena/RestAPI/hooks?access_token=secret',
  method: 'get',
  headers: 
   { host: 'api.github.com',
     'content-length': '0',
     'x-github-otp': 'two-factor-code',
     'user-agent': 'Meanstack',
     accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json' } }
STATUS: 200
HEADERS: {"server":"GitHub.com","date":"Fri, 15 Apr 2016 18:56:08 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"2","connection":"close","status":"200 OK"..."x-github-request-id":""}
entro en webhooks, no hay errores
entro en webhooks, en if
STATUS: 200
HEADERS: {"server":"GitHub.com","date":"Fri, 15 Apr 2016 18:56:08 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"2","connection":"close","status":"200 OK"...,"x-github-request-id":""}
entro en webhooks, no hay errores
entro en webhooks, en if
problem with request: timed out
[error] { [Error: 504: Gateway Timeout]
[error]   defaultMessage: 'Gateway Timeout',
[error]   message: '504: Gateway Timeout',
[error]   code: '504' } null 1izpena
{ [Error: 504: Gateway Timeout]
  defaultMessage: 'Gateway Timeout',
  message: '504: Gateway Timeout',
  code: '504' }
problem with request: timed out
[error] { [Error: 504: Gateway Timeout]
[error]   defaultMessage: 'Gateway Timeout',
[error]   message: '504: Gateway Timeout',
[error]   code: '504' } null 1izpena
{ [Error: 504: Gateway Timeout]
  defaultMessage: 'Gateway Timeout',
  message: '504: Gateway Timeout',
  code: '504' }
```

Any idea? Many thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that your API is taking too long to respond. This is most probably due to a bug in your code than caused by calling external API. May be you can share some code here so we can try to find the problem. Using a timeout middleware just normalize the case that your application hang for ever handling a web request.

Here i update your Web request handler ending the response where appropriate.

```
exports.auth = function auth (request, response) {
    var userid= request.params.userid;
    var username = request.body.username;
    var pass = request.body.pass;

    var arrRepos = [];
    var usertoken = "";

    if(userid !== undefined && userid !== null &&
            username !== undefined && username !== null ){

        Auth(request, response).then(function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                response.status(error.code).json({message: error.message});
                response.end();
                return;
            }

            if (userid !== result._id){
                response.status(401).json({message: 'Unauthorized. You are trying to access with a different userid'});
                response.end();
                return;
            }

            githubapiservice.getUserToken(userid, username).then(function (error,result){
                if(error){
                    response.status(error.code).json({message: error.message});
                    response.end();
                    return;
                }

                var newResult = {};

                if(result == null){

                    if(pass == undefined || pass == null || pass == ''){
                        response.status(400).json({message: 'Bad Request. Missing required parameters'});
                        response.end();
                        return;
                    }

                    githubapiservice.createToken(userid,username,pass).then(function (error,result){
                        if(error){
                            var messageJSON= JSON.parse(error.message);
                            response.status(error.code).json({message: messageJSON.message});
                            response.end();
                            return;
                        }

                        if(result == null ){
                            response.json({message: "No se ha conseguido el token, intentelo de nuevo más tarde"});
                            response.end();
                            return;
                        }

                        usertoken = result;

                        githubapiservice.saveUserToken(userid, username, result).then(function (error,result){
                            if(error){
                                response.status(error.code).json({message: error.message});
                                response.end();
                                return;
                            }

                            if(result !== null){

                                newResult.githubtoken = result;

                                githubapiservice.getRepositories(result).then(function (error,result){

                                    if(error){
                                        if(error.code == '504'){
                                            response.status(error.code).json({message: "Gateway Timeout"});
                                            response.end();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            var messageJSON= JSON.parse(error.message);
                                            response.status(error.code).json({message: messageJSON.message});
                                            response.end();
                                        }

                                        return;
                                    }

                                    if (result === undefined || result === null || result.length === 0){
                                        newResult.arrRepos = arrRepos;
                                        response.json(newResult);
                                        response.end();
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    newResult.arrRepos = result;

                                    githubapiservice.getWebHooks(newResult.githubtoken, result).then(function (error,result) {
                                        if (error) {
                                            var messageJSON = JSON.parse(error.message);
                                            response.status(error.code).json({message: messageJSON.message});
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            newResult.arrRepos = result;
                                            response.json(newResult);
                                        }

                                        response.end();
                                    });
                                });

                                return;
                            }

                            response.status(422).json({message: "Validation Failed"});
                            response.end();
                        });

                    }); /* end create token */
                } else {
                    newResult.githubtoken = result;

                    githubapiservice.getRepositories(newResult.githubtoken).then(function (error, result) {

                        if(error){
                            var messageJSON= JSON.parse(error.message);
                            response.status(error.code).json({message: messageJSON.message});
                            response.end();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (result === undefined || result === null || result.length === 0){
                            newResult.arrRepos = arrRepos;
                            response.json(newResult);
                            response.end();
                            return;
                        }

                        githubapiservice.getWebHooks(newResult.githubtoken, result).then(function (error,result) {
                            if (error) {


                                var messageJSON = JSON.parse(error.message);
                                response.status(error.code).json({message: messageJSON.message});
                                response.end();
                                return;
                            }


                            newResult.arrRepos = result;

                            response.json(newResult);
                            response.end();

                        });
                    });
                }
            }); /* end getUserToken */

        });
    } else {
        response.status(400).json({message: 'Bad Request. Missing required parameters'});
        response.end();
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, the code is quite long, but now I will add it in the answer.

Comment: Ok the two services are clear but i'm having trouble reading your Web handler. In your Web handler i recommned you to end the response every time you finish processing (every time you set a 4xx status) and return from the function to avoid any error.

Comment: Yes, I send the response with errors when its happen. I'll cut the controller code to make it more understandable.

Comment: I try to remove as much indentation as i could but you should keep improving this code because is very difficult to read given the amount of nesting levels.

Comment: I notice that you put response.end() and return; its ok, but in my case I think it is not a problem, because the only error that I have is timeout gateway when I get the repositories or weebhooks in the method. githubapiservice.getRepositories(result), and the client gets the response correctly. I think the problem is because I have misconfigured the server response time for requests because Internet latency varies, sometimes I get the error or not. I am not sure, but it is probably.

Comment: Anyway I'll try. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Izaskun Peña i put response.end() everywhere because you allways need to end the response explicitly. Otherwise the client will hang waiting for the end of response and a gateway timeout will appear.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and then I will make you feedback of this. Thanks again :D

Comment: Well, I change the code and appears new errors, I don't understand why.

Comment: The error is this:   [error] getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.github.com:443 null undefined
error al get repos
{ [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.github.com:443]
  defaultMessage: 'Internal Server Error',
  message: 'getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.github.com:443',
  code: '500' }
undefined:1
getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.github.com:443

Comment: Well, @yeiniel, I change the code with your recomendations and change the proxy to https instance of http and it works !!! I hope it is not because I rebooted the router. :P

Comment: Well then thank me by marking the answer as correct ;-)

Comment: May be you can try isolating the error source by customizing the error responses based on the particular operation its been performing.

Comment: I think that the problem is network latency. The problem is on githubapiservice.getWebHooks(). In the service, this method execute correctly for 4 times (function(item, callback)), but when the callback returns (, function(err, res){ ) 2 times ok and 2 times the error of gateway timeout.